# how to reward a customer that generates a sale

Tags: magento2, sales-order, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, refund

Let's say the shop sells once in a lifetime items. You won't buy again likely.
So I can't setup a discount for a customer A that bought an item already and then recommends that item/shop to another person B that then buys an item from the shop.
Also I don't want to discount possible customer B as this wouldn't benefit customer A.
To still stimulate the behaviour I would need to discount/refund customer A's already placed order if customer B buys an item.

What would be the best way to do this if there is any?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use "Adjustment Fee" and make the refund of order for customer A, you can refund how much you want to send to the customer and the rest set as Adjustment Fee to keep it.

Comment: Well you can always create a manual refund. But of course that should be at least semi automatic. So if customer B orders and enters a coupon code he will get a discount and customer A will automatically get a refund. Something like that maybe. Or customer A enters an email of customer B and if customer B generates a sale with that email A will get a refund. Or...

Comment: Another option is use points and rewards system extension , and make modification or manually make payout of points to customer A PayPal - just as another example